# Execute Webview in background without UI

Tags: android, android-webview, android-background, android-thread

In my app a use a `WebView` that displays a login screen. Once the user is logged in and the token expires, I reuse the Webview with the cached credentials in order to relogin. The thing is that I want to do this relogin action in the background, without the WebView to be visible.
Is it possible?

I tried to put in a transparent Activity but in this case the user can not navigate in the app until this process returns.

Comment: I do not know how you are implementing the `WebView` or refreshing the "logon"  with the `WebView`, but as far as I know the object will still be "usable" if its `Visibility` is marked `GONE`.

Comment: you can call api with users credentials. Share your code how you use webview in app/activity.

Comment: also, you can set visibility gone by default and when you got the response from URL then update visibility

Comment: Jigar's suggestion of maintaining the credentials would be the better solution. Why keep a `WebView` around if all you need is to stay "logged on"?

Comment: I don't want to "play" with the visibility attribute of the `WebView` because during this login process I want the user to be able to navigate in different screens of the app. Also I don't want to store the password of the user locally. Finallly I created a `Service` which contains the WebView inside a `WindowManager` with zero dimensions.